# How to choose between Enum and bool in c#?

Tags: c#, oop

I create a new `DataContract` and I need to add a new field.

That field will be describe a type of export job: Ad-hoc or virtual standby.
Which type do I need to choose to represent this idea: bool or enum? Why?

Comment: Enum. `bool` is for boolean values -- true or false.

Comment: But this field can have IsAdHocExport name

Comment: Will you have a second field IsVirtualStandBy? Will you be able to set both IsAdHocExport and IsVirtualStandBuy to true at the same time?

Comment: enums are more descriptive and extensible.

Comment: If possible, I'd look at interfaces instead of bool or enum values. Otherwise, an enum would be best.

Comment: @jeyoung No, I will not have the second field.

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow because it is about design practices and is inherently subjective. You might consider asking about considerations when making these types of decisions on Programmers.SE.

Comment: @Anatoly So what you're saying, it's either AdHoc or not AdHoc, which would be the only justification to use a bool. Otherwise, use an Enum.

Comment: In this case `bool` is a terrible idea.

Comment: @CodyGray when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider how it will be used as method parameter

```
void F(DataContract dataContract)
```

If it's Enum, you invoke it via

```
F(DataContract.AdHoc)      
F(DataContract.VirtualStandby)
```

They are all very clear. What if it's bool:

```
F(bool dataContract)
```

Then invoke it via

```
F(true)
```

Execute me! Is it Ad Hoc or Virtually Standy? You have educate every method consumer what true/false mean in this context. Even they want to write clear code by

```
F(true/*Ad Hoc*/);
```

It's really less readable.

Comment: If it's bool I invoke it like `F(isAdHoc)`

Comment: In some cases using enums can be an overkill and inconvenient. Also a side note about "educating method consumers", you can use XML notation to explain what the bool parameter does.      /// <param name="refreshCached">Forces to refresh cached data.</param>